# Can a website still recognize me if I use a VPN and clear my cookies?

Tags: vpn, security, privacy, private-browsing

I have a user account on some website, and want to create a new account on it using a VPN.
I don't want the website to connect the new account with the old one.
What are fingerprints that I should hide in order to prevent such tracking?
I'm using a laptop with Windows 10, and heard once that even the graphic card has some kind of a unique signature that websites can track. is this correct?

edit:
not sure why I need to update the question.

Comment: This has a good explanation of ways other than cookies that sites can use to track you: https://www.howtogeek.com/115483/htg-explains-learn-how-websites-are-tracking-you-online/

Comment: @LawrenceC wow. nice and scary. so how may one avoid that?

Comment: "not sure why I need to update the question." - It's unclear;  However, since you submitted an edit that asked why you had to update your question, instead of clarifying your question.  The only edit reviewers will see is an edit on an unclear question. This will make reopening your question difficult.  However, what you should not do, is submit the same question again.

Comment: Hiding your tracks online/protecting your online privacy is unfortunately complex.  The site I posted will help with the basics, but truly it is an in-depth topic.  Worth the study, but it's IMHO too broad to be effectively answered here.  Questions here should be able to have a definite precise answer--your question is a good question, but it's wrong for SuperUser to provide an simple and likely incomplete or opinion-based answer to a complex topic that isn't simple.  So I agree with the VTC reason.  No slight against you, my friend.